# Freemarker iterating a list of map eg: Map<String,List<String>> with pattern like menu subpages

Tags: freemarker

So i have a var with data sets
{
"keyval1="[
"sbcd1",
"sbcd2",
"sbcd3",
"sbcd4",
"sbcd5"
]
}

any idea ? how to iterate this thing

Comment: With `#list` directive (see documentation).

Comment: i was thinking to make it with map.

Comment: I'm talking about the `list` directive in the FreeMarker template language:  https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html. That can enumerate both `List`-s (and arrays etc.), and `Map`-s.

Comment: fine for key i will get on iterating it but i need to iterate the list of strings present in map value    ...    <#list map?keys as key>   i will get the key... noe need to itereate the value <#list>

Comment: I guess you need `<#list map as key, value>`. But it's on documentation page I linked earlier.

Comment: Thanks . i just fixed it by using a assign .. i got the variable from map value .. then i assigned it a variable by using assign .. then iterated that one with list.

Answer (score 0):

i just fixed it by using a assign .. i got the variable from map value .. then i assigned it a variable by using assign .. then iterated that one with list.

eg:

<#list maptobeiterated?keys as key>

```
<#assign innerlist= maptobeiterated[key]>

 <#list innerlist as listVar>

<i>!GOT IT! :)</i>

 </#list>
```

</#list>

Comment: Unless you are using an old FreeMarker (or some funny legacy `ObjectWrapper`), you should use `<#list map as key, value>`, instead of listing the map keys and then call `map[key]`. (Or, if you don't need the keys at all, you can just list `map?values`.)